# How to set a cell value in a multi header/multi index pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that looks like that:

```
             SPY                                          
            Open        High         Low       Close      
             Bid   Ask   Bid   Ask   Bid   Ask   Bid   Ask
Date                                                      
2010-01-01   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2010-01-02   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2010-01-03   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2010-01-04   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I want to set a specific cell value, for example open bid for date 2010-01-04 so I tried this:

```
df.ix['2010-01-04', 'SPY']['Open']['Bid'] = 10
```

but nothing has happened to the dataframe. When I remove `['Bid']` at the end values for both bid and ask change but I don't know how to change only one value at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use a `tuple` to get at the MultiIndex element
- `.ix` has been deprecated.  In this case, use `.at`.  `.loc` would also work, but `.at` is more efficient if getting at a particular cell.

---

```
df.at['2010-01-04', ('SPY', 'Open', 'Bid')] = 10
```