# Set cell value below headers created by MultiIndex - Pandas

Tags: pandas

[image]

What I'm looking forward to do is populate data inside cells below **Description** & **Status** column.

This is what I used to created the data shown in the image.

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Functional Checks'],['Description','Status']])
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(index=[],columns=header)
```

Comment: Can you descrive data used for filling?

Comment: I have updated my question. Just consider it be a simple 2-3 rows based string data.

Comment: Can you create data sample?

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you need sample data? The solution should probably be something like mentioned in `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266795/how-to-set-a-cell-value-in-a-multi-header-multi-index-pandas-dataframe` post.

Answer (score 0):

You need specify `index` first and then use [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Functional Checks'],['Description','Status']])
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5),columns=header)

data_frame.at[1, ('Functional Checks', 'Status')] = 'status1'
print (data_frame)
  Functional Checks         
        Description   Status
0               NaN      NaN
1               NaN  status1
2               NaN      NaN
3               NaN      NaN
4               NaN      NaN
```

Better is create `DtaFrame` by constructor like:

```
vals = [['a', 'status1'], ['b', 'status2']]
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Functional Checks'],['Description','Status']])
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=header, data=vals)

print (data_frame)
  Functional Checks         
        Description   Status
0                 a  status1
1                 b  status2
```